# Png Image inside a UIWebView Glitches

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, visual-glitch

I have a serie of transparent pngs which are part of several html pages bounded to separate `UIWebViews` (locally stored); each webview is inside a scrollview, so that I can slide between them.
To make thinks as light as possible, I dynamically load and unload the `UIWebViews` as I go through the scrollview. (I keep in memory only the current/prev/next and unload all the rest).
At this point, it happens that just a couple of these pngs gets glitches (not every time) as they are loaded.

[ here's the 1st glitch ]

[image: glitched png]

I'd like to know the reason why this happens, and why it only happens on 2 pngs out of 9.
And of course if you got a solution to that, it'd help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve the problem by splitting the png in two pngs.

the problem was generated by the fact that the png was 1.8Mb and it seems that UIWebViews has quite a bit of issues in memory handling over images.

Anyhow, this a very awkward thing. and I'm disappointed by the fact that we're at iOs 5.1.1 (and counting) and there are still those kind of issues.